# A list of all glossary (nomenclature) in Lyx

Tags: lyx, glossaries, nomenclature

I'm very new in Lyx and I plan to write an SRS in Lyx. I expect a lot of words, how I have to explain in a glossary. For this purpose, I use the nomenclaure (nomancl) which works well.

But I expect the following problem. In Lyx is no list of all defined or created glossary entries. I have a box named nomenclature and grey boxes starting with "nom" scattered anywhere in the document.

By the way, what I also use is notes for "todos".

I have noted with pleasure, in the navigation pane on the left, there is a list of all tocs and notes. But what i missed is a list of all glossary entries so I'm able to check, if I had already explain a word or not in Lyx.

I heared from another package named "glossaries", but I did't found, how to integrate this package in Lyx and if this package deliver a list of all defined glossary entries.

Can you give me a hint?  I use Lyx 2.0.0 on Windows.

Comment: Could you please specify what you mean with "I have a list of all notice"? Do you mean that in your nomenclature you get an output of a certain entry togehter with the page numbers this entry appears on?

Comment: Sorry for my english. i edit my post. with notice i mean notes, the litte yellow boxes.